# How do I luanch an external application from Ruby and wait for the user to close it

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, spawn

During the execution of a Ruby script I would like to open an external application (specifically Visual Studio Code on Macos) and wait for the user to close the window created by it before proceeding with the execution.

Currently I am using `Process.spawn` in this way

```
cmd = "/usr/local/bin/code #{path_to_file}"
pid = Process.spawn cmd
```

(`/usr/local/bin/code` is a link to the actual binary in the Applications folder)

Of course this does not work because the command returns immediately.

Visual Studio Code has the additional complication that it can launch a separate window with this command and I would like to wait for the user to close only that specific window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Process.waitpid`.

```
cmd = "/usr/local/bin/code #{path_to_file}"
pid = Process.spawn cmd
Process.waitpid(pid, 0)
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-waitpid2

Comment: `Process.spawn` exits immediately.